# Getting upper into lower case

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008-r2

In my SELECT statement, I have:

,UserName

When this comes through in the query, it appears as: JOHN.SMITH

Is it possible to use CAST or CONVERT to change this to John Smith?

Any advice gratefully appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: in php you can use ucwords http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

Comment: or this could help you. http://www.joellipman.com/articles/sql/t-sql/713-convert-to-proper-case-in-t-sql.html

Comment: Assuming this is to display more readable information to the user, why don't you store a friendly name to display to the user (like their actual name?)

Comment: AFAIK..there's no sql-server inbuilt function todo this,you might need write some functions,then use them in your operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First replace the period with a space:

```
SELECT REPLACE(SELECT UserName FROM YourTable, '.', ' ')
```

Save this in a variable, or put this select directly to the function below.

Unfortunately, I don't have t-sql at my disposal right now, so I can't check the syntax to be 100% correct.

Then to set only first chars to uppercase. If you were using oracle, I would tell you to use initcap, but this doesn't exist in t-sql.

Taken from link: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/17608

```
create function initcap (@text varchar(4000))
returns varchar(4000)
as

begin
    declare     @counter int, 
        @length int,
        @char char(1),
        @textnew varchar(4000)

    set @text       = rtrim(@text)
    set @text       = lower(@text)
    set @length     = len(@text)
    set @counter    = 1

    set @text = upper(left(@text, 1) ) + right(@text, @length - 1) 

    while @counter <> @length --+ 1
    begin
        select @char = substring(@text, @counter, 1)

        IF @char = space(1)  or @char =  '_' or @char = ','  or @char = '.' or @char = '\'
 or @char = '/' or @char = '(' or @char = ')'
        begin
            set @textnew = left(@text, @counter)  + upper(substring(@text, 
@counter+1, 1)) + right(@text, (@length - @counter) - 1)
            set @text    = @textnew
        end

        set @counter = @counter + 1
    end

    return @text
end
```

So use this function to convert the uppercase string. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could go about it like so:

`DECLARE @UserName AS varchar(50) = 'JOHN.SMITH'`

```
SELECT LEFT(UPPER(LEFT(@UserName, CHARINDEX('.', @UserName)-1)),1) + SUBSTRING(LOWER(LEFT(@UserName, CHARINDEX('.', @UserName)-1)),2,LEN(LEFT(@UserName, CHARINDEX('.', @UserName)-1))-1) + ' ' + LEFT(UPPER(RIGHT(@UserName, LEN(@UserName) - CHARINDEX('.', @UserName))),1) + SUBSTRING(LOWER(RIGHT(@UserName, LEN(@UserName) - CHARINDEX('.', @UserName))),2,LEN(RIGHT(@UserName, LEN(@UserName) - CHARINDEX('.', @UserName)))-1)
```

It gets everything before the `.` and then uppers the first letter whilst lowering the rest and then does the same for everything after the `.`.

However, it would be much better if you handled this in your code as when you come back to reading this query you may not know what it's doing.